# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot launch viewer. API GraphStream-Android

Tags: java, android, graph, graphstream

Hello i'm new in android developing and am doing a work for university, to create a app that can create graphs (of graph theory) and execute algorithms, I chose to use graphstream, because it is a graph library but i'm having some issues, I can't put the node on the View
the layout is in a fragment because i'm using two activits one to draw the graph and the other to choose the algorithm. (this is just a test to see if the graph appear in the screen, I will try to implement the buttons so that the user creates his own graph).

this is my java code:

```
package com.projeto.gabriel.athenatgfinal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.graphstream.graph.Graph;
import org.graphstream.graph.implementations.SingleGraph;
import org.graphstream.ui.android_viewer.DefaultView;

public class FragmentGrafo extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grafo_fragment, container, false);

   BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavView);
   bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(selectedListener);

   return view;
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener selectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_add_node:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicou em add nó", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_add_aresta:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "aresta aqui", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_remover:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "remover", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui.renderer","org.graphstream.ui.j2dviewer.J2DGraphRenderer");
   Graph graph = new SingleGraph("tutorial 1");

    graph.addNode("A" );
    graph.addNode("B" );
    graph.addNode("C" );
    graph.addEdge("AB", "A", "B");
    graph.addEdge("BC", "B", "C");
    graph.addEdge("CA", "C", "A");

    graph.display();
 }
}
```

this is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<org.graphstream.ui.android_viewer.util.DefaultFragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_tag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavView"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="369dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="287dp" />

<include layout="@layout/bottom_nav_view"
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is my bottomNavView that i'm trying to  put an event to click and draw nodes and edges and delete them:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_color"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_grafo">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

and this is my error:

> ```
> --------- beginning of crash
> ```
>
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.projeto.gabriel.athenatgf, PID: 6000
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot launch viewer.
>           at org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractGraph.display(AbstractGraph.java:212)
>           at org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractGraph.display(AbstractGraph.java:204)
>           at com.projeto.gabriel.athenatgfinal.FragmentGrafo.onCreate(FragmentGrafo.java:67)
>           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2414)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1418)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut(FragmentTransition.java:1195)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments(FragmentTransition.java:1078)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions(FragmentTransition.java:117)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2408)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2243)
>           at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:654)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:146)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:758)
>           at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:640)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>           at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6083)
>           at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
>           at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:690)
>           at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19857)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2275)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1366)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1619)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6338)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>           at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>           at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6169)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
>        Caused by: org.graphstream.util.MissingDisplayException: No UI package detected! Please use System.setProperty("org.graphstream.ui") for the selected package.
>           at org.graphstream.util.Display.getDefault(Display.java:55)
>           at org.graphstream.graph.implementations.AbstractGraph.display(AbstractGraph.java:209)
>               ... 58 more
>   Application terminated.

My question is how to correct this ?, this is the best way to do this?
thanks for read, plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Graphstream 1.3 and the regular display() method. If you want to develop an android application, you must use [Graphstream 2.0](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-core/tree/2.0-alpha) with the [Android UI](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-ui-android)

You can find some example [here](https://github.com/graphstream/gs-ui-android-test) to help you.

Comment: I did the import of the APIs as shown, but the org.graphstream.ui.android_viewer.util.DefaultFragment appears in xml 'The following classes could not be instantiated' and when I execute it appears java.lang.RuntimeException: Can not launch viewer. I tried to create the class display (Bundle savedInstanceState, Graph graph, boolean autoLayout) but it did not work, could you give me an example?

Comment: there are plenty of examples in the link I gave you. Look here: https://github.com/graphstream/gs-ui-android-test/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ui/graphstream/org/gs_ui_androidtestFull

Comment: Thanks, I read better what was in the link and following the code I was able to make the fragment work and draw the graph. Thank you very much.